# запрос каждые х минуты

Tags: php

Опять я. С тупими вопросами

Нужно отправлять запрос каждые х минуты.

Например
    if(время)
    {
Код
    }
    else
    {
Код
    }

определить времю now()
И отправить вопрос через 30мин.

```
else
выводить ошибку если не прошло 30мин.
```

Comment: планировщик заданий(Windows) и крон Cron линукс

Comment: Bloom, нужно чтоб работало без крона)

Comment: при клике можно сделать открытие другой вкладки передать туда числовой парметр установить set_time_limit() потом парметр sleep() и нужный код, вклдки будут всететь хоть несколько суток ожидать выполнения кода( естественно не выключая комп, и браузер)

Answer (score 2):

На линукс серверах за это отвечает crontab
вызвать: `crontab -e`
В нем нужно задать интервал времени и выполняемую команду
`*/15 * * * * php /var/www/example.loc/your_script.php`
В этом примере сервер будет каждые 15 минут запускать **your_script.php**

Comment: работаю.на хостинге) хочу сделать это бгз крона. Это для игры кликалки.

Comment: могу только предположить, что вы хотите   
``else
выводить ошибку если не прошло 30мин.``

Есть пользователь, который что-то "накликал" в игре и его нужно ограничить на 30мин.
Вам нужно хранить минимум две вещи, это его идентификатор и время последнего клика (в бд или файле)
тогда что-то в таком духе:
``$userId = 1;
$clickTime = strtotime("2019-07-19 16:10:33");
$currentTime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) - (30 * 60);
if($userId == 1 && $clickTime > $currentTime ){
    echo '30 мин еще не прошло';
}``

Comment: Время клика храниться в бд с id юзера) if($user['clicktime'] => time()-30*60){ } можно так*

Comment: супер. Это был пример "на коленке". Вариантов решения и оптимизации есть не один